# 日本人のかたですか vs 日本のかたですか

Tags: meaning, words

I originally received a post from an online chat which stated 「日本人のかたですか？」 I assumed this post was correct and questioned the meaning of the word かた in this instance. Would 「日本人のかたですか？」 be considered redundant? Would 「日本のかたですか？」 be the correct rewrite of the sentence with かた meaning person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “Nihon no kata desuka”
>   “Nihonjin no kata desuka”
>   “Nihon no hito desuka”
>   “Nihonjin desuka”

All of them are used.

There’s no difference in meaning, but “kata” sounds polite, “Nihonjin desuka” can be rude. 
 “Nihonjin no kata” has two words that means “person”, but it’s grammatically correct.

Because there’s “desuka”(敬語), we wouldn’t say “Nihonjin desuka”. It doesn’t suit “desuka”.

Comment: この暗室は暗い。(It’s dark in this darkroom.) and 最も悪い悪人は彼だ。(The worst bad guy is he.) are also used.

Comment: え、「日本人ですか」って言わないのですか？確かに「日本の方でしょうか」とかのほうが丁寧で初対面の人に対して使うのに適切だと思いますが、「日本人ですか」も、少しくだけた状況(大学生の間だとか)だったら普通に使われているかと…

Comment: 日本人かどうか尋ねるのは外国人っぽい顔をしていた時くらいで、そういう場合は大抵外国人ですか？とかハーフですか？と言いますね。可能性があるとすれば警察に職務質問をされた時くらいで、その場合は日本人の方ですか？となると思います。日本人ですか？はやはり外国人に見える人に向けて言うのは失礼にあたると思いますが、大学生くらいの年齢なら言ってしまうことも少なくないかもしれませんね。