# 方 【かた】or 方 【ほう】?

Tags: readings

In this sentence, what is the reading of 方?

「京都【きょうと】の方【?】から『京都【きょうと】にはおしゃれ過【す】ぎる人【ひと】はいない、“過【す】ぎる”は恥【は】ずかしいことです』と聞【き】きました

*"I heard from a Kyōtoite that there are no overly fashionable people in Kyōto, and that 'too much' is something to be ashamed of," she said.*

https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/culture/tv/20220803-OYT1T50243

I can imagine different logics for the two different readings. If it is read  方 【かた】, perhaps one can interpret the sentence as "the way they do things in Kyōto"; however, if it is read 方 【ほう】, perhaps it means, "over there in Kyōto, ..." However, experience teaches me that there is no sense in trying to deduce a logical answer from a foreign language; one simply needs to know the correct answer and memorize it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's かた. Do you remember かた can respectfully refer to a person by itself? 京都のかた means the same thing as 京都の人.

- [Meaning of 方 in 「質問のある方はどうぞ」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74106/5010)
- [Translating: "一人でも多くの方にコメントしていただけたら嬉しいので "](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8113/5010)
- [日本人のかたですか vs 日本のかたですか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70081/5010)